# How to resolve duplicate slot presence in this case? [Vue]

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Currently I am getting this error:

> Duplicate presence of slot "default" found in the same render tree -
>   this will likely cause render errors.

Although there are some examples on how to fix this I don't know exactly how to resolve this in my case.

This is the markup I am using in my PHP file for my search component.

```
<search>
    <form action="#" class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="number_persons">Persons</label>

            <select class="form-control" name="num_persons">
                <etc>
            </select>
        </div><!-- /.form-group -->
    </form>
</search>
```

My `.vue` search component has a template that looks like this:

```
<template>
    <div class="item" v-for="item in items">
        <div class="alert alert-warning" v-show="prices">
            <slot></slot>
        </div>

        <pagination></pagination>
    </div><!-- /.items -->
</template>
```

From the documentation I see you are to use something like scoped slots? I have tried implementing them but I can't get it to work. I have simply tried adding scope to the `form` in the PHP file and the vue component.

Can anybody possibly tell me what syntax to use in this case?

Updated example from @Cobaltway

https://jsfiddle.net/31x0cy2p/1/

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://jsfiddle.net/31x0cy2p/

Comment: @Cobaltway sorry I was not being clear with my example. I have added a loop since that is where it is going wrong. On repeat of the default slot.

Comment: @Cobaltway your updated Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/31x0cy2p/1/

Comment: Is it your goal to have the slot reproduced n times identically?

Comment: @Cobaltway yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For scoped slot, a `<template>` element in the parent, with a property scope, seems to be mandatory, as specified in the third example [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Scoped-Slots). It must be a template element, it does not work with anything else.

> In the parent, a `<template>` element with a special attribute scope
> indicates that it is a template for a scoped slot. The value of scope
> is the name of a temporary variable that holds the props object passed
> from the child.

```js
Vue.component('search', {
  template: `
    <div>
      <div v-for="n in 10">
        <slot :text="n"></slot>
      </div>
    </div>`
});

new Vue({el:'#app'});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <search>
    <template scope="props">
        <form action="#">
            <div>
                <label for="number_persons">Person {{ props.text }}</label>
                <select name="num_persons"></select>
            </div>
        </form>
    </template>
  </search>
</div>
```

Comment: From the vue.js site: `In 2.5.0+, slot-scope is no longer limited to <template> and can be used on any element or component.`